# Need clarity on Sleep mode in MLX90614 IR sensor

Tags: stm32, sleep, sensors, i2c

I am working on the MLX90614 IR sensor. In the [datasheet](https://media.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx90614-datasheet-melexis.pdf), they have given some steps to put the sensor but somehow I am not able to understand it clearly. A detailed description of the RAM and EEPROM access is given there. However, how to put the sensor in sleep mode is not much clear.

[image]

In another section of commands, they have given an opcode for entering sleep mode. But again there is no much information about **usage of the opCode**.

[image]

I am quite successful in using the sensor to read the object's temperature. But putting sleep mode is not helping me anywhere.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to send the commands as below, but it seems not working.  i2cdata[0]= MLX90614_OP_SLEEP;
 i2cdata[1]= 0xE8;
 HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c4, (MLX90614_DEFAULT_SA << 1), i2cdata, 1, 0xFFFF);

Comment: you are only sending one byte

Comment: try: HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c4, (MLX90614_DEFAULT_SA << 1), i2cdata, 2, 0xFFFF);

Comment: Also put your code in the post, not in the comments.

Comment: I have actually randomly tried sending 1 byte and 2 bytes. Just to have some experiments as I am not clearly understanding the description in the datasheet.

Comment: did you try transmit_IT(...)? what is the return value of the transmit function? are you seeing an ACK or NACK from the sensor? how do you know that the sleep is not working? Give us some more debugging information.

Answer (score 2):

As per page 22 of the datasheet, you need to send a write with 0xFF to the sensor.

[image]

PEC is some CRC and and they apparently already did the math for you.

So you need to send:

0xB4 0xFF 0xE8

(Double check the I2C address and read/write bit, I'm never sure if the given address is shifted or not. Edit: 0xB4 is shifted and 8th bit 0 for write already added, so no need to do anything else).

Comment: Yes as per this datasheet, I have tried to send the commands as below, but it seems not working in actual. So, I doubt how that is it correct steps to add or does this sensor any steps.             MLX90614_OP_SLEEP = 0xFF;   i2cdata[0]= MLX90614_OP_SLEEP;         i2cdata[1]= 0xE8; HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c4, (MLX90614_DEFAULT_SA << 1), i2cdata, 2, 0xFFFF);